# Data.table: dynamically select group by variables using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I am trying to develop an app that allows the user to select which variables are used in the 'by'section of a data.table.

Supose the mtcars dataset is loaded into the app, in the UI there will be a select like:

```
vector.vars <- c('am', 'gear', 'carb')
selectInput("vars", "Select variables:", as.list(vector.vars), selected = 'am', multiple = TRUE)
```

this select input will be render in the UI and when the user selects some of the variables in the server will be used like:

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
  d <- mtcars[, list(mpg_mean= mean(mpg), by=input$vars]
  })
```

In this case if the user selected 'am'and 'carb' the preceding scripts should perform this operation:

```
  d <- mtcars[, list(mpg_mean= mean(mpg), by=list(am, carb)]
```

and show the mean of 'mpg' for each combination of 'am' and 'carb'.

... BUT the by=input$vars does not work as intended.

Any ideas in how I can reach the desired output,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(mpg_mean = mean(mpg)), by = c(input$vars)]
```